# Chatango turning my custom css links blue

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I am rather new and hope this isn't a dumb thing to ask but I am making a layout for chatango and I have edited my `CSS` etc. but when I put it on chatango the links turn blue instead of what the `CSS` says I have searched Google but can't seem to find the issue in this:

```
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#0eac17;}
    a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #7ff900;
    background-color:#222222;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border-bottom-width:2px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color:#1faf29;}
    a.navigation:link {
    color : #b27c98;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    display : block;
    height:20px;
    font-size:14px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #333333;
    font-family: Times new Roman;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    line-height:20px;
    margin: 12px 0px 2px 1px;}
    a.nav:visited {
    color : #b27c98;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    display : block;
    height:20px;
    font-size:14px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #333333;
    font-family: Times new Roman;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    line-height:20px;
    margin: 12px 0px 2px 1px;}
    a.nav:active {
    color : #b27c98;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    display : block;
    height:20px;
    font-size:14px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #333333;
    font-family: Times new Roman;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
    line-height:20px;
    margin: 12px 0px 2px 1px;}
    a.navigation:hover {
    color : #7ff900;
    background-color: #222222;
    width: 150px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border-bottom-width:2px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color:#1faf29;}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/RgAAX/3/` 
And here is what chatango turns it into : `http://prntscr.com/3ihxgc`

This issue seems to be in both ff and chrome and perhaps others as well but I have not tried any others
Edit: The suggested !important; has fixed the link issue thanks alot c:

Comment: If the answer I provided is correct, please select it as the answer.

Comment: My apologies did not see the check mark at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `!important` after the color declaration...

```
color:#0eac17!important;
```

This is a good introduction on the `!important` declaration...

[!important CSS Declarations: How and When to Use Them](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/)

If you apply it to `a` you will also have to apply it to `a:hover`